# Parent child relation using mysql

Tags: mysql, join, parent-child

I have a sample mysql table named `relation` as follows:

```
ID  TypeID  Name         Parent_ID
----------------------------------
1    1      Parent        0
2    2      Child1        1
3    2      Child2        1
4    3      GrandChild1   2
5    3      GrandChild2   2
6    3      GrandChild3   2
7    3      GrandChild4   3
8    3      GrandChild5   3
```

How can I generate a report like given below using mysql queries.

```
ParentName  ChildName   GrandChildName
--------------------------------------
Parent      Child1      GrandChild1
Parent      Child1      GrandChild2
Parent      Child1      GrandChild3
Parent      Child2      GrandChild4
Parent      Child2      GrandChild5
```

Comment: please ensure that the desired output is correct.

Comment: Yes... I want some pivoted type report from the main table. The `Parent_ID` gives the parent name of a child. So according to my idea, I can pivot/transport using the relation between `Parent_ID` and `ID`

Comment: @Subrata Dey - Added a solution. But like to know any other methods.

Comment: Frankly,I was going to do mostly in that way. Why don't you like the way?
What does "EXPLAIN" output say? Are you worrying about performance?

Comment: I am a newbie to mysql. So Iike to review my query for better one. So posted the qn here @SubrataDey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about the performance of this query then you can check the performance running the above query preceding the word "EXPLAIN".

```
    EXPLAIN select 
      rl.Name as 'ParentName', 
      rl1.Name as 'ChildName',
      rl2.Name as 'GrandChildName'  from relation rl
    INNER JOIN (select * from relation where TypeID=2) rl1 ON rl.ID=rl1.Parent_ID
    INNER JOIN (select * from relation where TypeID=3) rl2 ON rl1.ID=rl2.Parent_ID
```

If you see that performance is not quite good then you can create an index On TypeID.

**Here is a link on mysql Explain :**

http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

```
CREATE INDEX Idx_TypeID relation(TypeID);
```

And change the above query like below :

```
select rl.Name as 'ParentName', rl1.Name as 'ChildName',rl2.Name as 'GrandChildName'  
from relation rl
INNER JOIN (select * from relation where TypeID=2) rl1 ON rl.ID=rl1.Parent_ID
INNER JOIN (select * from relation where TypeID=3) rl2 ON rl1.ID=rl2.Parent_ID
WHERE rl.TypeID=1
```

**Note : I've added a where clause in the last line for making use of the index (Idx_TypeID) just created.**
(performance gets better.)

Now check this query again preceding the word "EXPLAIN". This time you will get a better explain output. Good day!

**EDIT :**

The sub-queries can be avoided. Thanks to ***mpsbhat*** for pointing out an important point what I missed out earlier.
So here is the query I've directly quoted from mpsbhat's post:

> ```
> SELECT
>   rl. NAME AS 'ParentName',
>   rl1. NAME AS 'ChildName',
>   rl2. NAME AS 'GrandChildName'
> FROM
>   relation rl
> INNER JOIN relation rl1 ON rl.ID = rl1.Parent_ID
> AND rl1.TypeID = 2
> INNER JOIN relation rl2 ON rl1.ID = rl2.Parent_ID
> AND rl2.TypeID = 3
> ```

If you explain the query it shows better performance than the previous.

Comment: Is there any methods to avoid sub query?

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by

```
select rl.Name as 'ParentName', rl1.Name as 'ChildName',rl2.Name as 'GrandChildName'  from relation rl
INNER JOIN (select * from relation where TypeID=2) rl1 ON rl.ID=rl1.Parent_ID
INNER JOIN (select * from relation where TypeID=3) rl2 ON rl1.ID=rl2.Parent_ID
```

I like to know any other methods.

**EDIT:** Here is another method that I found without inner query as given below which is I really wanted to achieve.

```
select rl.Name as 'ParentName', rl1.Name as 'ChildName',rl2.Name as 'GrandChildName'  from relation rl
INNER JOIN relation rl1 ON rl.ID=rl1.Parent_ID and rl1.TypeID=2
INNER JOIN relation rl2 ON rl1.ID=rl2.Parent_ID and rl2.TypeID=3
```

Comment: Thanks mpsbhat. I missed out this point earlier.And if you think about performance then surely it's better!

Comment: Thank you Subrata Dey for your nice explanation about performance improvement using indexing.